# How to handle the duplicate key when kstream-kstream join

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

KStream-KStream join is a window join and allows duplicate keys.

Join operation creates a changelog topic and rocksdb Statestore.

RocksDB is a key-value store.

But how does kstream handle duplicate keys?

Comment: RocksDB does not allow duplicate keys. Neither do compacted segments of Kafka topics

Answer (score 0):

The changelog is stored in a compacted topic. It is for fault tolerance reasons. In the StateStore is just the current representation of the state(so one entry for each key).
Maybe this give you a starting point:
https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/stateful-fault-tolerance/ or
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/architecture.html#fault-tolerance